# Javascript - Validate a text as AND/OR expression

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following expression text

```
(1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4)
```

This is the input to a form, and i want to validate if it is valid expression. Missing parenthesis or miss spelling of AND/OR... I want this rule to be valid. This is only an example. I want the validation to work for any expression rule.

```
1 OR (1 AND 2) OR (1 AND (2 OR 3))  //Valid
1 OR (1 AND 2) OR (1 (2 OR 3))  //Not Valid
1 OR (1 AND 2) OR (1 AND (2 OR 3)  //Not Valid
1 OR (1 AND 2) OR (1 AND (2 O)R 3  //Not Valid
```

Comment: Nothing so far... I don't know how to start

Comment: I can't understand the down voting of the question!

Comment: simplistic approach: step 1: check that `()` balance ... step 2: remove them ... step 3: check that every second word is AND or OR

Comment: `I can't understand the down voting of the question!` - stack overflow expects you to try to solve the problem yourself

Comment: I want ideas not code... And yes the "simplistic approach" is everything i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, think about the parens. Parse from left to right. You could have a counter that increments with ( and decrements with ). If it's ever negative your expression is invalid. If it is non zero at the end then it's invalid.

Then strip the parens from the expression and check for the regular expression

```
^\d+\s+(AND|OR)\s+\d+(\s+(AND|OR)\s+\d+)*$
```

which looks for

```
(start)integer, some whitespace, integer
```

followed by zero or more

```
some whitespace, integer
```

Comment: balancing parens ... `!s.match(/[()]/g).reduce((r, b) => r < 0 ? r : (b == '(' ? r + 1 : r - 1), 0);`

Comment: Nice approach of removing the parens. I was trying to solve it like the execution... But there is no reason... Thanks

Comment: @Michalis Have removed the comment about interview/homework ;-) Good luck with the project and if you're happy please consider marking as accepted.

Comment: The "correct" way to solve this is to parse the expression into a binary tree where the boolean operator is the branching node and the children are either integers or sub trees.

Comment: check the last example to my question. I have some count of open and close parens but it is not valid. I have to make more complicated analysis to find if the paranthesis is valid. But I think I know how... I will post later my code. Thanks